# GitHub API - Equivalent of GitLab's Protected branch API

Tags: github, github-api

There is a feature named [Protected branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#protect-repository-branches) on GitLab API. Basically, you can restrict all the push and merge access by setting their levels to 0.

I have checked [Branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/) section on GitHub REST API document but I couldn't find the equivalent API. How can I restrict merge and push to a branch on GitHub? Also, I want to remove this restriction after some operations.

```
protect master branch (do not allow any push, merge etc.)
do something
unprotect master branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Going to the github api documentation, I see they have added [protections](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#update-branch-protection). This seems pretty clear how to add proctections using API now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way using the API, but in the UI, you can go to `settings` > `branches` and then add some protection rules

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests)